# finding largest sum of array of credit cards

Tags: javascript

I am interested in finding the credit card number whose digits sum to the largest number. If more than one has the same largest sum of digits, I want the last one in the list with that sum.

I am trying to write a single function that takes one argument. That argument will be an array of credit card numbers. Assume the array can have any number of credit card numbers and each one is a string of digits and dashes. The function should return the credit card number that has the largest sum of digits.

Here is what I have so far-

```js
function getSum(stringLength) {
    var stringLength = ['1476-0089-5132-7420', '2034-6002-3978-5567', '6647-1123-5895-0038'];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < stringLength; i++);
    for (string = 0; string < [3]; stringLength++);
    //stringLength + i =Sum ;

    if (0 > 1, 2) {
      return string(0);
    } else if (1 > 0, 2) {
      return string(1);
    } else(2 > 1, 0) {
      return string(2);
    }
    console.log('1476-0089-5132-7420', '2034-6002-3978-5567', '6647-      1123-5895-0038');
    console.log('The Larget Sum is:' + true);
  }
  /*criteria for code: Contain all variables and code needed within      a function.
  Have that function take one argument which will be an array of credit card number strings.
  Determine the sum of digits for each credit card number.
  Determine which credit card number has the last largest sum of digits.
  Use a return statement to return the required card number in its’ original form.*/
```

Comment: This code is a mess. `for (i=0;i< stringLength;i++);` doesn't have anything in the body of the loop. `for (string= 0 ;string< [3];stringLength++);` also has no loop body, and `string < [3]` makes no sense -- why would you compare a number to an array?

Comment: `stringLength++` makes no sense, since `stringLength` is an array, not a number. What is `if (0 > 2, 3)` supposed to mean?

Comment: What is `return string(0)` supposed to do? There's no `string()` function, `string` is the name of the variable in your second `for` loop.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that tries to add the digits of the card number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

Note: `;`is used to end a statement, so when you do `for(...);` loop ends there and it does not do anything.

```js
var cardNos = ['1476-0089-5132-7420', '2034-6002-3978-5567', '6647-1123-5895-0038'];

var largestSum = cardNos.reduce(function(p,c){
  return Math.max(p, getSumOfDigits(c))
}, 0);

function getSumOfDigits(str){
  var s = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').split("");
  return s.reduce(function(p,c){ return +p + +c});
}

console.log(largestSum);
```